# Using an Array in author_id int references user(id)

Tags: postgresql, postgraphql

On https://github.com/calebmer/postgraphql the author shows a schema:

```
create table post (
  id serial primary key,
  author_id int non null references user(id),
  headline text,
  body text,
  …
);
```

How would I have to rewrite the schema if I would like to cite multiple authors and reference them using an [array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html)?
Would it be: `author_id int[] non null references user(id)`?

Comment: Not possible. You can not use arrays in foreign keys (any direction). You need to model that with a proper many-to-many relationship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You can. But you must not.

### with a check constraint

You can add a check constraint with a function that controls that.

Disadvantage: It's not a foreign key

### with a trigger and an auxiliar table

You can add a table `post_author` and populate it with a `On insert or update` trigger.

Disadvantage: It's triky and duplicates info.